# why file is downloading without extension?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

The file is stored in my app folder `App_Data` and when I download it, it downloads with the name "Download" and file type is `File` I want to download the file with the original name and its right extension. Any Help?

```
public ActionResult DownloadsFile()
{
    var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files"));
    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
    List<string> items = new List<string>();

    foreach (var file in fileNames)
    {
        items.Add(file.Name);
    }

    return View(items);
}
```

```
<div class="st-pusher well" style="overflow:scroll;" id="content">
<br><h3 style="margin-left:10px; text-align:center;">Download Files</h3>
<div style="border: 1px solid silver; margin:10px 10px 0px 10px; padding: 10px; border-radius: 4px; background-color:white;">
    <table style="width:100%;" class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
        @for (var i = 0; i <= Model.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model[i].ToString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { FileName = @Model[i].ToString() })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

```
public FileResult Download(string FileName)
{
    return new FilePathResult("~/App_Data/Files/" + FileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/FileResult.cs#L25

Comment: Wild guess: do you have "hide extensions" switched on, locally?

Comment: no "hide extensions" is not switched on locally @HansKesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are not setting the [FileDownloadName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.filedownloadname(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.FileResult.FileDownloadName) of the `FilePathResult`.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
return new FilePathResult("~/App_Data/Files/" + FileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet)
{
    FileDownloadName = "SetTheFileName"
};
```

The `FileDownloadName` property will set the content-disposition header of the response, and that will be used by the Save File dialog of the browser